# Giving up sin for accepting dua

Tags: dua, sin

I am doing one sin long time (more than 10yrs Please include me in your duas). But now I have dua that I wish very very to accept by allah. So i give up all the sins and started doing good indeeds.

But whenever I inteneted or tempted to do that sin, I think about that dua to be accepted and I will change my mind.  So I afraid that instead of giving up sin for allaah.

Is it permissible to avoid that sin for dua to be acceptance. I afraid that whether my niyyath is wrong or I should afraid of allah when I tempted to do that.

Allah know the best.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamualaikum my brother. Us human will never be an exceptional in making sins. It's how that we seek for Allah forgiveness when doing those wrong things.

It is good that you stop doing the sins and make more dua to Allah. However, as a human being we cannot control whether the dua to be accepted or not. What we can do is just to have faith in Allah. To be patient and sincere in life and hope for the best. Allah knows what's the best for you, at the correct moment. And if you wish for something and it turns out that there are better things for you, Allah will replace them.

Therefore brother, correct and sincere your niyyath. Have faith and be patience. Just don't stop to make dua in your everyday prayer. In sha Allah one day, you will get what's the best for you.